# R function to get a projected map centered on a point of interest

Tags: r, gis, r-sp

Is there an easy way to project sp object around a location of interset.

Example: I work on Russia, how can I project to have reasonable flat projection, similar to what I get when centering on that country in GoogleEarth?

```
library("rworldmap")
russia <- countriesCoarse[which(countriesCoarse$ADMIN=="Russia"),]
plot(russia)
```

Gives me that:

[image]

Quite far from the geometry of that:

[image]

Note: I'm not just interested in the map, but also in the projected coordinates themselves (as an sp object) to be able to use them in calculations, particularly with rgeos.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way with `ggplot2`, its extension `ggalt` (not really needed, but `geom_map` is kinda broken atm) and the `maps` package:

```r
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
mapa <- map_data('world', 'Ru')
ggplot() +
    geom_cartogram(map = mapa, 
             data = mapa, 
             aes(long, lat, map_id = region),
             color = 'black',
             fill = 'grey') +
    coord_map('polyconic') +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Note the `'polyconic'` projection, I just think is nice, feel free to adjust

Comment: As I precised in the edit, I can I get the coordinates (the sp object), not just a map?

Comment: The `mapa` objects contains the coords, I think you can easily transform to `sp`

Comment: copy pasting your code I get:  Error in as.vector(y) : attempt to apply non-function

Answer (score 1):

The Extended Transverse Mercator is a nice option. To stay in R packages not dependent on ggplot representation, you can use `spTransform` from sp/rgdal packages. The following function is extracted from [spatDataManagement package](https://bitbucket.org/cmbce/r-package-spatdatamanagement/overview).

```
Project<-function(obj,objRef=obj){
    xlim <- range(coordinates(obj)[,1]) # bbox(objRef)[1,]
    ylim <- range(coordinates(obj)[,2]) # bbox(objRef)[2,]
    cp <- c(mean(xlim),mean(ylim)) # ~baricenter of the map
    stringProj <- paste0("+proj=etmerc +lat_0=",cp[2]," +lon_0=",cp[1],
                         " +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
    polysProj <- spTransform(x=obj,CRSobj=CRS(stringProj))
    return(polysProj)
}

 library("rworldmap")
 russia <- countriesCoarse[which(countriesCoarse$ADMIN=="Russia"),]
 projRussia <- Project(russia)
 par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 plot(russia,main="Lat/Long projection")
 plot(projRussia,main="Projected nicely")
```

[image]